# Proper way to save a javascript canvas path into a database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, canvas

What is a proper way to save a javascript canvas path to a mysql database using php.

The path can look something like this:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    0 => "M"
    1 => 127.83333333333
    2 => 70.486111111111
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    0 => "Q"
    1 => 127.83333333333
    2 => 70.486111111111
    3 => 128.33333333333
    4 => 70.486111111111
  ]
  2 => array:5 [
    0 => "Q"
    1 => 128.83333333333
    2 => 70.486111111111
    3 => 129.41666666667
    4 => 70.486111111111
  ]
  3 => array:5 [
    0 => "Q"
    1 => 130
    2 => 70.486111111111
    3 => 130.83333333333
    4 => 70.486111111111
  ]
]
```

But is in most cases larger.
Further there can be multiple paths(arrays) linked to a entity let's say `user_id`. What is a good way to manage this in my database. One could serialize the data or use `json_encode`, but I am not sure if that is really the way to go.

Comment: Can you describe each value in the arrays? I haven't played with js and canvas for years. Just need to be sure about the elements, before I give you an answer.

Comment: Do you also need to search in the paths in the MySQL table to filter results?

Comment: @RaymondNijland, no the api shall just give each path

Comment: Well storing it in a NoSQL database might make more sense here, as you are planning to store non relational data

Answer (score 0):

Check for serialize php function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

It returns storable representation of your array (string), which you can keep in database. And then when you need it back you can unserialize it.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Keep in mind security? -> ***"Warning

Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize() regardless of the options value of allowed_classes. Unserialization can result in code being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and autoloading"*** As stated in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)..  *"Proper way to save a javascript canvas path into a database"* i would not trust running `unserialize()` on data which comes from a client...

Answer (score 0):

You ***cannot*** store arrays directly into the database.

You need to convert into a string and then store in a database.

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert your array in a string and then send to ***PHP*** file for storing into database.
[Know More About JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

Suppose you are storing all these values in some javascript array call `canvasValues`

Then use convert array to string `JSON.stringify(canvasValues)`

Now you can make an AJAX call to your ***PHP*** file that will save your canvas array values in a database.
I am here using [AXIOS](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make a call to a ***PHP** file.

```
axios.post("yourPhpFileName.php",{
  "arrayValues": JSON.stringify(canvasValues)
})
.then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.error(error);
});
```

Now in your PHP file

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
    $userInput = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
    $arrValues = json_decode($userInput["arrayValues"], true);

    #now user foreach() to loop around your $arrValues variable
    foreach($arrValues as $key => $values){
         #now extract your data and do whatever you want
    }

    # Before saving $arrValues in DB, convert back to string using json_encode();
}
```